# Clustering Large Data Matrix using R

Tags: r

I have a large data matrix (33183x1681), each row corresponding to one observation and each column corresponding to the variables.

I applied K-medoids clustering using PAM function in R, and I tried to visualize the clustering results using the built-in plots available with the PAM function. I got this error:

```
Error in princomp.default(x, scores = TRUE, cor = ncol(x) != 2) :
cannot use cor=TRUE with a constant variable
```

I think this problem is because of the high dimensionality of the data matrix I'm trying to cluster.

Any thoughts/ideas how to tackle this issue?

Comment: I note that you have 7 questions on SO so far, and have accepted 0 answers.  It is important to the continued functioning of the site that you go back and mark answers as accepted by clicking the check box next to the answer that solved your problem.  You even get a little rep bonus for doing so.

Comment: Can you clarify what package you are using. I am aware of the `pam()` function in package **cluster** but not which package provides function PAM.

Comment: As regards the error message, which I misread before supplying my Answer, I don't know what `x` is in the error message but if it is your data then does `sapply(x, function(x) length(unique(x)))` return any values that are `== 1`. The error is saying that for one or more variables are constant in your data.

Comment: Gavin, I know what the error does mean. It doesn't make sense though as I have no constant variables in my data. In fact, I reduced the dimensionality of the matrix up to 20% and the error has gone. So I think the problem is with the dimensionality of the array.

Comment: And I wonder why my question is down voted?

Comment: @HassanSaif I would debug `pam()` (via `debugonce(pam)`) to see where the error is coming from. Clearly by the time `princomp.default()` sees whatever `x` is, there are constant columns (i.e. with zero variance). I wouldn't have thought that the dimensionality itself would cause the problem; R would complain about not enough memory if that were the case, unless there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I'll check that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `clara()` function in package **cluster** which is shipped with all versions of R.

```
library("cluster")
## generate 500 objects, divided into 2 clusters.
x <- rbind(cbind(rnorm(200,0,8), rnorm(200,0,8)),
           cbind(rnorm(300,50,8), rnorm(300,50,8)))
clarax <- clara(x, 2, samples=50)
clarax

> clarax
Call:    clara(x = x, k = 2, samples = 50) 
Medoids:
         [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -1.15913  0.5760027
[2,] 50.11584 50.3360426
Objective function:  10.23341
Clustering vector:   int [1:500] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
Cluster sizes:           200 300 
Best sample:
 [1]  10  17  45  46  68  90  99 150 151 160 184 192 232 238 243 250 266 275 277
[20] 298 303 304 313 316 327 333 339 353 358 398 405 410 411 421 426 429 444 447
[39] 456 477 481 494 499 500

Available components:
 [1] "sample"     "medoids"    "i.med"      "clustering" "objective" 
 [6] "clusinfo"   "diss"       "call"       "silinfo"    "data"
```

Note that you should study the help for `clara()` (`?clara`) in some detail as well as the references cited in order to make the clustering performed by `clara()` as close to or identical to `pam()`.

Comment: Why did you choose 50 samples for the clara algorithm? CRAN's Cluster pdf doesn't say much on the sample variable besides "integer, number of samples to be drawn from the dataset. The default, 5, is rather small for historical (and now back compatibility) reasons and we recommend to set samples an order of magnitude larger."

Comment: It seemed logical to break this into 10 chunks and 50 is an order magnitude greater than the default.

Comment: This is a new package for me, so I don't understand the use for sampling. What do you plan on accomplishing by subsampling that way?