# R large distance matrix in vegan

Tags: r, memory, hierarchical-clustering, vegan

I am running R 3.2.3 on a machine with 128 GB of RAM. I have a large matrix of 123028 rows x 168 columns. I would like to use a hierarchical clustering algorithm in R, so before I do that, I am trying to create a distance matrix in R using the vegdist() function in the vegan package with the method Bray-Curtis. I get an error about memory allocation:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20668704), nrow = 123028))
library(vegan)
mydist <- vegdist(df)
```

> Error in vegdist(df) : 
>     long vectors (argument 4) are not supported in .Fortran

If I use the pryr package to find out how much memory is needed for the distance matrix, I see that 121 GB are needed, which is less than the RAM that I have.

```
library(pryr)
mem_change(x <- 1:123028^2)
```

> 121 GB

I know there used to be a limit of 2 billion values for a single object in R, but I thought that limit disappeared in recent versions of R. Is there another memory limit I'm not aware of?

The bottom line is that I am wondering: What can I do about this error? Is it really because of memory limits or am I wrong about that? I would like to stay in R and use a clustering algorithm besides k-means, so I need to calculate a distance matrix.

Comment: You could always calculate it piecewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R can handle long vectors just fine, but it seems that the distance matrix calculation is implemented in C or Fortran and being interfaced with R using `.C` or `.Fortran`, which do not accept long vectors (i.e. vectors with length > 2^32 -1) as arguments. See the docs [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html), which states:

> Note that the .C and .Fortran interfaces do not accept long vectors,
>   so .Call (or similar) has to be used.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/blob/543f633fb750234b77a9a43230a8878606f84b93/R/vegdist.R) for the `vegdist()` function, it looks like your matrix is being converted into a vector and then passed to a function implemented in C to calculate the distances. The relevant lines of code:

```
d <- .C("veg_distance", x = as.double(x), nr = N, nc = ncol(x), 
        d = double(N * (N - 1)/2), diag = as.integer(FALSE), 
        method = as.integer(method), NAOK = na.rm, PACKAGE = "vegan")$d
```

And therein lies your problem. When your matrix is cast to a vector, it becomes a long vector, which is not supported by `.C`. You will have to look for a different package to calculate your distance matrix (or implement one yourself).

Comment: Thanks! This did answer the question about why I'm getting the error. My next question is what can I do about it? I can try doing it piecewise as Alex suggested above, but are there any other existing functions that will calculate Bray-Curtis distance on a larger matrix?

Comment: @jk22 As a first step, you should contact the vegan authors. They are very helpful in my experience, and may be able to find a solution that can be incorporated into future vegan releases.

Comment: @jk22 Doing a quick google search yields the [ecodist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecodist/) package that has the `bcdist()` function to compute Bray-Curtis distances. I'm not sure if it handles larger matrices or not.

Comment: Also, I would follow the suggestion made by @Tyler and contact the vegan authors about your problem so that the issue may get resolved.

Comment: I'm here (a vegan author). The analysis is correct: `vegdist()` does not handle long vectors. I have no plans to change this, because I don't have hardware were I could use long vectors (memory is exhausted first), but I'll welcome fixes (vegan is in github). Function `designdist` is in pure R and may handle long vectors, but it uses more memory for temporary objects (3x more). Similarly `dist(x, "manhattan")/as.dist(outer(rowSums(x), rowSums(x), "+"))` is Bray-Curtis, but uses memory for temporary objects. In addition, anything you do will need huge amounts of CPU time: is it worth it all?

Comment: Thanks to all for the ideas and information. @Jari Oksanen, I appreciate your response, and indeed, I am considering whether it is worth it to use such a large matrix. One alternative that is appealing is a k-means clustering with a large number of clusters, followed by a hierarchical clustering of the k clusters, similar to the suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984940/clustering-very-large-dataset-in-r/21990387#21990387). One hesitation with doing it that way is that I'm not sure that further analysis on a hierarchical clustering of the k clusters will be straightforward.